# Rails 4: Masonry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, masonry

I've installed the [Masonry gem](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/masonry-rails) both using my gemfile:

```
gem 'masonry-rails'
```

...as well as from the console:

```
$ gem install masonry-rails
Successfully installed masonry-rails-0.2.4
Parsing documentation for masonry-rails-0.2.4
Installing ri documentation for masonry-rails-0.2.4
Done installing documentation for masonry-rails after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

I've restarted my app, but when I call:

```
//= require masonry/masonry
```

in my application.js, I see the error:

```
couldn't find file 'masonry/masonry' with type 'application/javascript'
```

...any thought on why this might occur?  I've used the CDN successfully, but wanted to switch over to the gem.  I've also tried requiring `masonry` rather than `masonry/masonry` with no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
//= require masonry/masonry
```

if you don't use jQuery

Otherwise you should include jquery.masonry

```
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you restarted your server?

If so, I advise you to perform manual installation by uploading masonry file in the vendors folder and manually writing the code to the product.js.